# How to determine if <option> tag is being clicked?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this,

```
<select id="rid" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;" name="rid">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

In my script, I want to know if for instance Option 1 is being selected or being clicked. What I'm trying here is to know an option is being clicked via the `<option>`'s attribute `value`. If an option is being clicked I will `alert()` something telling me that that option is being clicked. How would I do that in my `js` script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you concerned about clicks and not change then use `.click` event.

```
$('#rid').click(function () {
   if ($(this).val() == "1") {
      console.log("option 1 was clicked");
     //^- Using alert here would block the selection.
   }
});
```

Above is based on what is in OP -

> If an option is being clicked I will alert() something telling me that that option is being clicked.

As per -

> I want to know if for instance Option 1 is being selected or being clicked.

Comment: Yes, but it's unusable... You can never change the value ! (with alert)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus That is if you going to alert.. but are you going to alert in real scenario?

Comment: Vega : based on what is on OP... ;) (I'm not the downvoter by the way, it's just that the OP's question is not exactly feasible).

Comment: @Archer `console.log("` instead of `alert`.. Alert simply will block the click/change

Comment: So now it's not what the OP asked for.  I corrected your mistake for a reason :sigh:

Comment: @Archer It is again scenario based and from the usability point showing an alert on click of a select is simply bad. I believe the alert what is asking for is just for test purpose and what he really want is to get the value of the selected option.

Comment: If the alert is for testing purposes then why did you change it?  Also, he specifically asks about identifying an option - not all options.  I'd just rather give them what they ask for and offer alternatives and explanations, where relevant.  Don't worry about it - different strokes for different folks :)

Answer (score 5):

something like that

```
$('#rid').change(function() {
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGpGx/)

or checking for specific value, even before onchange

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rid = $('#rid');
    alertForOne(rid.val());
    rid.change(function() {
        alertForOne(rid.val());
    });

});

function alertForOne(val) {
    if (val == 1)
    alert('test');
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YGpGx/1/)

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/ptX9t/)**

```
$('#rid').change(function(){
     alert($(this).val());
});
```